# Generalizing a function that returns a callable based on an object and a class method

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-phoenix

I am trying to write a template function that returns a callable object based on an object and a class method. The idea is:

```
class Obj : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Obj>
{
public:

    bool Meth1(int a)    { return a == 7; }
    int  Meth2(double a) { return a * 2;  }
};

template<class Tobj, typename Tmeth>
auto Creator(boost::shared_ptr<TObj> shobj, Tmeth meth) -> decltype("callable based on Tmeth")
{
    return boost::bind(&meth, shobj, _1);
}
```

The usage would be something like:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Obj> obj = boost::make_shared<Obj>();

// mm would be of type boost::function<bool(int)>
auto mm = Creator(obj->shared_from_this(), Obj::Meth1);

bool isSeven = mm(7);
```

I cannot find a way of doing this. As a fun fact, while experimenting, one of my desperate tries was something like:

```
template<class Tobj, typename Tmeth>
auto return_mm(Tobj &obj, Tmeth meth) 
     -> decltype(boost::bind(&meth, obj.shared_from_this(), _1))
{
     return boost::bind(&meth, obj.shared_from_this(), _1);
}
```

I know, looks silly and it makes the VC++10 to crash. Any idea? Maybe should I use boost::phoenix?

**Update:**

This compiles and works on VC++10 but, seriously, looks awfull:

```
template<typename TOBJ, typename TMETH>
auto Create(boost::shared_ptr<TOBJ> sobj, TMETH mm) -> decltype( boost::bind(mm, sobj, _1) )
{
    return boost::bind(mm, sobj, _1);
}
```

The part " -> decltype( boost::bind(mm, sobj, _1) )" does not look good to me. Also if you try to use it with a method expecting two parameters it breaks the compiler!

Comment: You pass `obj` by value to `Creator`, so it is destroyed at end of scope, and binding use so an invalid object.

Comment: It's true. I was just trying to explain the basic idea and didn't take care about the details because I don't have a clue of how doing this. Sorry.

Comment: I am just looking for advice. Just wondering if this is possible because I am not very sure if can actually be implemented.

Comment: Now, `obj` is destroyed when it goes out of usage scope, and when `mm` is destroyed (because of the `shared_ptr`). Changing `Obj obj;` into `std::shared_ptr<Obj> obj = std::make_shared<Obj>();` is maybe what you want (or maybe get rid of `shared_ptr` completely, depend of lifetime of your objects).

Comment: True, if I declare it to inherit from enable_shared_from_this I should at least use it :-)  I'm so worried about finding the way that I'm not thinking on the most basic things

Answer (score 0):

Fixed some errors in your code

**Updated.** Added `boost::function` example.

```
class Obj : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Obj>
{
public:
    bool Meth1(int a)    { return a == 7; }
    int  Meth2(double a) { return a * 2;  }
};

template<class Tobj, typename Tmeth>
auto Creator(boost::shared_ptr<Tobj> shobj, Tmeth meth)
{
    return boost::bind(meth, shobj, _1);
}

template<typename Targ, class Tobj, typename Tmeth>
boost::function<bool (Targ)> Creator2(boost::shared_ptr<Tobj> shobj, Tmeth meth)
{
    return boost::bind(meth, shobj, _1);
}

int main() {
    boost::shared_ptr<Obj> obj = boost::make_shared<Obj>();

    // mm would be of type boost::function<bool(int)>
    auto mm = Creator(obj->shared_from_this(), &Obj::Meth1);
    boost::function<bool (int)> mm2 = Creator2<int>(obj->shared_from_this(), &Obj::Meth1);

    bool isSeven = mm(7);
    cout << isSeven << endl;
    cout << mm2(7) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result on [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/LVRnD4)

Comment: Ok, It seems that I was getting confused while learning about this stuff. VC++10 does not compile this code. It throws error C3551, expecting for a return value.

Comment: So, it seems that on more modern compilers this is allowed (to return auto without specifying anything else)

Comment: You can use `boost::function` as a result type of `Creator`. I've updated the example on Ideone.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, but the main thing I wanted is make it general (return some kind of auto). Just wondering how to make it work on older compilers (the Creator() function)